# how to get the incremental id of _form-opc - Dynamic Form Yii2

Tags: javascript, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have dynamic forms wbraganca working on Yii2, I would like to know how I can get the id of `_form-opc`, for example to get the id in `_form` I use:

```
    $(".dynamicform_wrapper").on("change","select",function(){
        var id=$(this).attr("id");
        var optionsInput=id.match(/^([a-zA-Z]+)\-([0-9]+)/g)[0]+'-justify';
    ..... }
```

but do not know how I can get the incremental ID of `_form-opc`,for example, `MoreOptions-0-n-option`, where n is the number of times I have created items. Them would appreciate it if you could guide me.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to your question, it is, however, another way to do it. Why don't you use a class to get the IDs?

You can have

```
<...id="MoreOptions-0-n-option"... class="MoreOptions">
<...id="MoreOptions-1-n-option"... class="MoreOptions">
```

Afterwards you would just go through all the elements with the class MoreOptions and get the ids or values.